# Cross-Distro NFS Mount Not Fully Writeable in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, centos, nfs, amazon-web-services

I'm relatively new to setting up NFS mounts and I'm trying to get things started in the AWS cloud. I ultimately want to have a CentOS box which serves as the NFS server and can have different sorts of machines (Ubuntu or CentOS) access the NFS share with full read/write access. I've got it somewhat working, but right now I can't write to files on the Ubuntu client that weren't created/last modified on the Ubuntu system. (As a test, I just created a text file on the Ubuntu client which was fine. If I then modify it on a CentOS system, I can read it in Ubuntu fine but I can't write to it any more.)

## Configuration:

On the CentOS server my /etc/exports file is as follows:

```
/hello *(rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)
```

(I just used the wildcard for now for ease of access - only systems in my specific AWS security group can actually access the NFS ports.) The config options were somewhat brought together from different guides on the Internets. I read somewhere that the fsid=0 is key to getting the share to be mountable in Ubuntu. I then exported with `exportfs -a`

On both an Ubuntu and CentOS client, I made the directory (with superuser/as root) `/mnt/mymnt` then ran:

```
mount -t nfs4 <MY_CENTOS_SERVER_DNS>.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/ /mnt/mymnt
```

to mount the share.

## Permissions

On the CentOS server, the shared directory permissions look like:

*(from ls -l /:)*

```
drwxrwxrwx.   2 1000 1000  4096 Apr 24 16:13 hello
```

A directory listing of /hello on the server yields:

```
total 8
-rw-rw-r--. 1   1000   1000  0 Apr 23 20:21 HELLO_CLIENT
-rw-rw-r--. 1 centos centos 17 Apr 24 16:05 HI_CENTOS
-rw-rw-r--. 1 centos centos 47 Apr 24 16:13 HI_UBUNTU
-rw-rw-r--. 1   1000   1000  0 Apr 24 16:24 TEST2
```

On the Ubuntu server, the same directory listing yields:

```
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody     nogroup    4096 Apr 24 16:24 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root       root       4096 Apr 23 19:07 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody     nogroup       0 Apr 23 20:21 HELLO_CLIENT
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody     nogroup      17 Apr 24 16:05 HI_CENTOS
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody     nogroup      47 Apr 24 16:13 HI_UBUNTU
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody     nogroup    0 Apr 24 16:24 TEST2
```

On a CentOS client, I see the same thing, but with the group `nobody` instead of `nogroup` (likely a syntactical thing).

## Summary

I'm trying to fully share a directory from CentOS server to both CentOS and Ubuntu clients over NFSv4. I can mount the share but I can't write to files I didn't create on the Ubuntu system on the Ubuntu system. Do I appear to be configuring something incorrectly? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you check to which groups your user belongs on the different systems?

Comment: Sure, they're as follows:

**centos user on Server:** `centos adm cdrom dialout floppy video dip audio`
**ubuntu user on Ubuntu client:** `ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev`
**centos user on CentOS client:** `centos adm cdrom dialout floppy video dip audio`

Not sure if there's a specific group they should all belong to but currently don't...

Comment: Hopefully you can read that formatting, tried the best I could!

Comment: Just a try. Let's do again your test:  create a text file on the Ubuntu client (see `ls -l yourfile` on both clients). Then modify it on a CentOS system, verify that you can read it in Ubuntu you cannot write it any more ans see again `ls -l yourfile` on both client. Edit your question if something is changed. If so maybe you have different user id on the two client and the program you used modified the ownership.

Comment: Just gave that a try. Seemed to be the same result. Interestingly, when opening that file in vim, it was marked as `[readonly]` but if I "force-write" (`:w!`), it will successfully write the changes regardless of system.